# TS2740: Missing properties from type when using spread operator

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object mocking out an Angular `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` ( [see definition](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/13.2.2/packages/router/src/router_state.ts#L255-L386) ). All the props are mocked out. I am then creating another mock object by just spreading the first object's props into the second.

```
export class AddEditResolverMocks {

    static routeWithId: ActivatedRouteSnapshot = {
        params: { id: 123 },
        data: { entity: EntityTypes.PayBillCycle },
        url: [],
        queryParams: {},
        fragment: '',
        outlet: '',
        component: '',
        routeConfig: null,
        root: new ActivatedRouteSnapshot(),
        parent: new ActivatedRouteSnapshot(),
        firstChild: new ActivatedRouteSnapshot(),
        children: [],
        pathFromRoot: [],
        paramMap: null,
        queryParamMap: null,
    };
    static routeWithoutId: ActivatedRouteSnapshot = {
        ...this.routeWithId,
    };
}
```

I thought it would bring over all the props, but VSCode seems to complain with:

```
Type '{ 
    url: UrlSegment[]; 
    params: Params; 
    queryParams: Params; 
    fragment: string; 
    data: Data; 
    outlet: string; 
    component: string | Type<any>; 
    routeConfig: Route; 
}' is missing the following properties from type 'ActivatedRouteSnapshot': 
 - root, 
 - parent, 
 - firstChild, 
 - children, 
 - and 3 more.ts(2740)
```

When I let VSCode refactor it, the "missing" props are added and the error goes away. So why it not work without explicit initialization? ( feel I am missing something stupid )

I am also surprised that VSCode is allowing a `this` reference in a static initializer.

**UPDATE**:
Changing `this` to `AddEditResolverMocks` :

```
 static routeWithoutId: ActivatedRouteSnapshot = {
        ...AddEditResolverMocks.routeWithId,
    };
```

had no effect.

**UPDATE 2:**
Added definition of ActivatedRouteSnapshot in desc as per comment.

Comment: yep - added an update. Feel there's something weird going on.

Comment: Also add the definition of *ActivatedRouteSnapshot*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that these missing properties are not present in the definition of the *ActivatedRouteSnapshot* class. They are actually getters, not attributes.

However, when there is a getter property without an equivalent setter, the *"compiler"* assumes this as readonly, which forces you to inform this attribute in the way you are creating the object instance.

But even though you have informed the attributes in this specific instance, the routeWithId variable definition is still *ActivatedRouteSnapshot*, which does not have these attributes.

For the error to disappear, just remove the definition of the variable:

```ts
export class AddEditResolverMocks {

    static routeWithId = {
        params: { id: 123 },
        data: { entity: EntityTypes.PayBillCycle },
        url: [],
        queryParams: {},
        fragment: '',
        outlet: '',
        component: '',
        routeConfig: null,
        root: new ActivatedRouteSnapshot(),
        parent: new ActivatedRouteSnapshot(),
        firstChild: new ActivatedRouteSnapshot(),
        children: [],
        pathFromRoot: [],
        paramMap: null,
        queryParamMap: null,
    };
    static routeWithoutId: ActivatedRouteSnapshot = {
        ...this.routeWithId,
    };
}
```

Still, I recommend that you don't instantiate these objects this way. The most appropriate is to use the `new` operator and pass the parameters via the constructor.

Also because the constructor performs some operations when receiving these parameters, something you are not doing when instantiating this way. And the extra attributes you are inserting shouldn't exist in this class.

Comment: "The most appropriate is to use the new operator" ... that is utter nonsense.  Javascript supports many paradigms, and Object-Oriented Programming (where you make pseudo-classes and instantiate them with `new`) is just one approach.  Creating objects directly with object literal syntax (ie. `{}`) is also a 100% viable approach, and in fact most modern JS devs prefer that more "functional" style (often combined with the "factory function" pattern) over the OOP approach.